# Editing .jar file by removing dependent jars and then replacing them

Tags: java, jar

I am working on a task that would remove two dependent .jars from a master .jar and then adding them back to the original .jar. It might not make sense, but there is a reason why this is needed.

The original structure of a jar is something like this:

```
project.jar
-- SUBFOLDER  
-- classes   
-- lib
     -- dependency1.jar
     -- dependency2.jar
     -- dependencyN.jar
```

I need to remove *dependency1.jar* and *dependency2.jar* from the original jar and then add them back.

When I remove the dependencies, the jar runs, but some of the functionalities of the application won't - that's fine. When I add the jars back, that's where the application doesn't work at all.

I tried to use jar utility `jar -uf project.jar dependency1.jar dependedncy2.jar`, zip utility, I also tried to unzip the jars and only add classes to the project.jar.

I am getting the following error when trying to execute with the updated Jars:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to
> get nested archive for entry BOOT-INF/lib/Dependency1.jar
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchive(JarFileArchive.java:104)
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive$NestedArchiveIterator.adapt(JarFileArchive.java:237)
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive$NestedArchiveIterator.adapt(JarFileArchive.java:228)
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive$AbstractIterator.next(JarFileArchive.java:189)
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.createClassLoader(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:87)
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:55)
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open nested jar file
> 'BOOT-INF/lib/Dependency1.jar'
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:288)
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:274)
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchive(JarFileArchive.java:100)
> ... 6 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to open nested entry 'BOOT-INF/lib/Dependency1.jar'. It has been
> compressed and nested jar files must be stored without compression.
> Please check the mechanism used to create your executable jar file
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromFileEntry(JarFile.java:314)
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromEntry(JarFile.java:296)
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:285)
> ... 8 more

It seems like compression is the issue there - is there a good way to manipulate a jar like this?

Comment: If the working (original) jar has the dependencies under `lib/`, that may be a requirement, and if so you must add them back in the required way i.e. from a subdirectory `lib/`

Comment: ["Doesn't work"](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/17-errors) doesn't help

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, I am adding them to the required directory in the jar.

Comment: @g00se, thank you! When I clarified the question, I actually resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using -0 or --no-compress operation modifier solved the issue.

EXAMPLE:
`jar -u0f myProject.jar target/directory/Dependency.jar`